# Zoom meetings inexplicably dropping for my child

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, troubleshooting, zoom-meeting

This is the weirdest problem I've ever faced (certainly over 25 years as a computer scientist and former IT admin). My son is taking Spanish classes with one provider and tutoring online with another. They were working fine until a few weeks ago when I upgraded my TP-Link Deco P9 firmware to the latest. Then it started happening. My son would be in his lesson for a few minutes and it would say "meeting was ended by host" or sometimes nothing at all. Joining again and again would result in the same drops within varying timespans (I haven't been rigorous but usually less than 5 mins).

Facts:

- I have a corporate account and a free account. My wife has a corporate account.
- I have a Windows desktop and 3 Windows laptops, 1 android tablet, an iPhone and an Android phone.
- My wife and I both hold Zoom meetings for 1+ hours on different devices, but mostly the laptops and the iPhone, sometimes with two-way video... basically zero problems.
- We've used both types of account (signed out and signed in).
- Latest Zoom is installed on every device.

What I've tried for my son:

- All devices on wifi with one provider and two of the laptops with the other
- A wired laptop
- A laptop connecting to the Internet using my Android mobile hotspot (this one really surprises me)
- A laptop connecting to the Internet over a VPN (wifi)
- A tablet over wifi that stayed connected to one provider for more than 30m with two-way video (no motion, no real interaction, just testing)
- Google Meetings on a laptop
- Skype on a laptop
- Facetime on the iPhone

Again, this exclusively happens when my son is in an online meeting. At times I've been in the room with him and sometimes not. He's not touching anything on the device.

I want to say it's only these two providers but incredibly, we also had it happen a couple times when he was speaking in Spanish with my brother-in-law and niece on Zoom (laptop).

I haven't tried going somewhere else yet and I haven't tried connecting audio via phone only.

The only two *known* commonalities that I can think of across all tested scenarios are my son's face/voice and the fact that his interactions are in Spanish.

At this point I'm starting to get really worried for fall when he goes "back" to school (f'in COVID). I'm pretty desperate for other suggestions.  Thanks in advance for any advice!

Comment: It could easily be the host who is dropping (especially if the host has flakey internet or flakely modem / router combination.

Comment: That could be the case except that each provider has claimed no other problems whatsoever with any other students or meetings.

Comment: So then my second part - hoster's personal equipment including their router.

Comment: @MarcC Great details in question! I am putting my hypothetical thoughts - The laptop he is using might not have proper fonts, someone sends message in Spanish, his zoom leads to errors. Again I don't know this could happen now but it used to happen very long time ago.

Comment: try restoring the previous firmware version  (They were working fine until a few weeks ago when I upgraded my TP-Link Deco P9 firmware)....

Comment: @John three separate hosts (though one is most frequent)...no reported problems with other meetings. I would say that reduces the probability that it's them *except* that all Spanish language "Zoomers" might have something installed on their systems that we don't, causing an incompatibility.

Comment: @wb3 My initial thoughts were absolutely the firmware (and I will try to either revert or replace) but after trying VPN *and* mobile hotspot (which uses Google Fi on Pixel 3), that hypothesis seems less likely.